# Clean way to declare these kinds of table in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I need to use a static table in my C++ program to lookup combinations.

This is a simple example (my table would be 3-4 times larger):

```
int TABLE[3][3] = {
           /*2*/ /*4*/ /*8*/ 
    /*2*/   {4,    8,    16},
    /*4*/   {8,    16,   32},
    /*8*/   {16,   32,   64}
};
```

I like this kind of table since it's very easy to lookup combinations from indexes and also it's easy to see the combinations.

However I do not like the fact that the 'keys' are only defined in comments which seems wrong.

Have anyone defined similar tables in code and are there any general recommendations?

Edit: My table cannot be computed. It's program specific 'settings'.

Comment: Out of interest, do the real keys follow some scheme? (In your example, they're consecutive powers of 2).

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1112531/96780 and its top voted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1112543/96780. They might be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, my keys are 0,1,2,n so indexing comes naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the constant look-up time, and don't want to use `unordered_map` (for example, because you can trivially avoid the hash computation), you could separate the coding from the lookup.

1. Code the data as a friendly-to-type-and-read structure including metadata:

   ```
   struct TableElement {
       int row;
       int col;
       int val;
   } raw_table[] = {
       {2, 2,  4}, {2, 4,  8}, {2, 8, 16},
       {4, 2,  8}, {4, 4, 16}, {4, 8, 32},
       {8, 2, 16}, {8, 4, 32}, {8, 8, 64} };
   ```

   (you can probably make something more beautiful with a bit of work)
2. initialize a fast look-up from this (once, at start-up). This could be:

   - a sparse array for no index computation, as in the second half of Joachim's answer,
   - a dense array for better cache behaviour
   - or even that `unordered_map` with a custom hash function

Comment: Great, I will investigate this approach. Also, I just realized that I'm actually doing double dispatch as the "cells" in my tables will be function pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you *also* tagged your question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you can always use a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) inside another `std::unordered_map`:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>> TABLE = {
    { 2, { { 2,  4 }, { 4,  8 }, { 8, 16 } } },
    { 4, { { 2,  8 }, { 4, 16 }, { 8, 32 } } },
    { 8, { { 2, 16 }, { 4, 32 }, { 8, 64 } } }
//    ^      ^   ^
//    |      |   |
//    |      |   value at [row][column]
//    |      |
//    |      column
//    row
};

// ...

std::cout << TABLE[1][5] << '\n';  // Outputs `0`
std::cout << TABLE[4][6] << '\n';  // Outputs `0`
std::cout << TABLE[4][4] << '\n';  // Outputs `16`
```

---

In plain C there is no way of having specific values at specific "keys" without padding your arrays:

```
int TABLE[9][9] = {
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  4,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0, 16 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  8,  0, 16,  0,  0,  0, 32 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0, 16,  0, 32,  0,  0,  0, 64 }
};
```

However you should be careful not to overstep the indexes, as you will then index out of bounds.

Comment: This looks great. I wonder if std::map wouldn't be faster with small tables though, lookups should be as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

In comes C++11:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using std::vector;
  vector<vector<int>> table = {
       /*2*/ /*4*/ /*8*/ 
       /*2*/   {4,    8,    16},
       /*4*/   {8,    16,   32},
       /*8*/   {16,   32,   64} };
}
```

For `std::array`, this will do the trick:

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
  using std::array;
  array<array<int,3>,3> table = {{
       /*2*/ /*4*/ /*8*/ 
       /*2*/   {4,    8,    16},
       /*4*/   {8,    16,   32},
       /*8*/   {16,   32,   64} }};
}
```

Also think about not using multidimensional arrays, but instead using a 1D array with indexing tricks.

Comment: Using std::vector or std::array is great, but I'm still left with the row/column definition in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you just hate these comments, the simplest way is definitely macros.

```
#define _(x)

int TABLE[3][3] = {
          _(2)  _(4)  _(8) 
    _(2)   {4,    8,    16},
    _(4)   {8,    16,   32},
    _(8)   {16,   32,   64}
};
```

^_^

Comment: That's actually pretty great :D